# Sort posts by multiple meta key values

Tags: customization, order

I'm not new to wordpress, but I'm not very good at PHP. I hope someone can help me, since I already tried to search for a solution for over 5 hours with no luck.

So I have an archive.php page where I want to to sort the posts by 3 meta keys. They all have numeric values. These are the names of the meta fields: "vorstellung-filmdatum" (The date), "vorstellung-uhrzeit-stunde" (The hour) and "vorstellung-uhrzeit-minute" (The Minute).

At this moment I'm using the following code, but it only sorts by the last meta-key ("vorstellung-uhrzeit-minute" in this case).

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'meta_key' => 'vorstellung-filmdatum', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'ASC', 'meta_key' => 'vorstellung-uhrzeit-stunde', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'ASC', 'meta_key' => 'vorstellung-uhrzeit-minute', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'ASC', ) );
query_posts( $args );
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

How can I change this to be sorted by all three meta keys?

I want it to sort the posts like this:

-- Date 1

--- Hour 1

------ Minute 1

------ Minute 2

--- Hour 2

------ Minute 1

------ Minute 2

-- Date 2

--- Hour 1

------ Minute 1

etc.

Can someone help me?

Comment: if it´s not too late, I´d add another meta with exact time and date in it´s value and sorted posts by that one. It also saves you multiple post meta per post as you have all necessary information in a single meta value.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to store the complete date-time in one meta field, saving it as an timestamp in the metafield and converting it by php datetime object functions for displaying.

**Step 1)**
Create a Metabox with a text input for entering the date + time. You can find a good introduction to meta boxes [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box#Procedural).

Step 1.5) if you want it to be easily usable, you can add a jquery plugin for date/time picking in the post edit screen, like [this one](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/).

**Step 2)**
in the myplugin_meta_box_callback function, convert the meta value $value into your desired display format using the php datetime functions like this:

```
if($value){
   $date = date_create($value);
   $value = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i');
}
```

**Step 3)**
In the save_metabox action, convert the date/time-Value by the php strtotime function to an unix timestamp like this:

Replace:

```
 $my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['myplugin_new_field'] );
```

with:

```
 $my_data = strtotime($_POST['myplugin_new_field']);
```

**Step 4)**
In your archive, give your query the `orderby` "meta_value_num", ordering it by numerical meta values of your custom field

**Step 5)**
Do NOT use query_posts.

**Step 6)**
Check in your while loop if the day of the current metavalue is higher than the day of the last metavalue

```
$day = 0;
while $query->have_post {
    $query->the_post;
    $newday = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'NAME_OF_METAFIELD',true);
    $newdate = date_create($newday);
    $newday = date_format($newdate,'d');
    if(!($newday==$day)) {
        $day = $newday;
        echo "Date:".date_format($newdate,'Y-m-d');
    }
    echo "Time:".date_format($newdate,'H:i');
    //All the other stuff that needs to be displayed
}
```

**Step 7)**
Done (more or less)... Do some tweaking

I didn't include the if-then stuff for the hour, but I think you can figure it out^^